# Is the set of pairs of TMs at least one of which accepts the empty word semi-deciable?

Tags: computability, undecidability, semi-decidability

L = { < M1,M2 > | M1,M2  are TM's and Ɛ ∈ L(M1) ∪ L(M2) }

Where Ɛ = Epsilon

**I know that this language is undecidable, but why it is semidecidable too.**

**What i have tried is =>**

Using Rice's Theorem, part 2

T(no) = (0,1)^+ and T(yes) = (0,1)*

Which gives that T(yes) is not a subset of T(no), and this says that it is semidecidable.

**Is my understanding right ?**

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rice's second theorem can be used to show for some sets that they are not semi-decidable, but not the opposite.

In order to show that this set is semi-deciable, just follow the definition and construct a semi-decider.

> *Idea:* Simulate both $M_1$ and $M_2$ on $\varepsilon$ simultaneaously using [dovetailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_(computer_science)). If either one halts and accepts, stop simulating and accept.